# Make a class extend a generic trait in Scala

Tags: scala

I thought this should work to make a light alternative to type classes but it does not :

```
trait Summable[T] {
  def sumWith(other: T): T
}

implicit class StringSummable(s: String) extends Summable[String]{
  def sumWith(other: String): String = s + other
}

def sumAll[T <: Summable[T]](list: List[T]): T = {
  list.reduceLeft((sum, element) => sum.sumWith(element))
}

sumAll(List("1","2","3"))
```

I have this error : `inferred type arguments [lang.this.String] do not conform to method sumAll's type parameter bounds [T <: Summable[T]]`

Is there a trick to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: How do you want to achieve?Even if typing is fixed, code will fail at sum.sumWith(element) because sumWith is not a method of String.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use a typeclass for this?

Comment: @prms it is using StringSummable extension on String

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov just for the curiosity and to epxlore the typesystem possibilities
Indeed right now I'm using type classes for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a "trick", it's literally a single-character change:

```
':' -> '%'
```

from subtyping to "implicit convertibility" bounds:

```
trait Summable[T] {
  def sumWith(other: T): T
}

implicit class StringSummable(s: String) extends Summable[String]{
  def sumWith(other: String): String = s + other
}

def sumAll[T <% Summable[T]](list: List[T]): T = {
  list.reduceLeft((sum, element) => sum.sumWith(element))
}

sumAll(List("1","2","3"))
```

Note that this tends to fall apart rather quickly. For example, as soon as you need a zero-ary function that returns an empty `String`, you are essentially out of luck with this approach, whereas it is trivial with a typeclass (as `Monoid[T]` shows). Without it, you can't even define `sumAll` properly, because it doesn't work on empty lists.

Note that the historical development so far has been *away from implicit conversions*, and towards the typeclasses, not the other way round.

Comment: View bounds are deprecated, `implicit ev: T => Summable[T]` should work. One thing I don't get is why not use a typeclass for this though?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Oh, so they aren't just frowned upon, they are officially deprecated? Good!

Comment: Thanks @AndreyTyukin! It would be better with monoid indeed, but it's just a stupid simple example for proof of concept. Indeed typeclasses are used a lot more but I was wondering if this approach could not be interesting and simpler for beginners? In other words I don't know where are the limits of this approach compared to typeclasses (except that it's clearer to see the implicit evidence in method signatures)